# how to find the derivative of $ f(x)=\int_x^{x^2}g(t)dt $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

$$
f(x)=\int_x^{x^2}g(t)dt
$$

$f'(x)=?$
first integrating the value of f(x) then differentiate f we can find.But how do i directly manipulate

Answer (score 3):

Let $$G(x)= \int_{0}\limits^{x} g(t)dt$$

then $$G'(x)=g(x)~~~~and~~~~~f(x)= G(x^2)-G(x)$$
by chain rule we get
$$f'(x)=2xg(x^2)-g(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

differentiating with respect to $x$ we get
$$f'(x)=2xg(x^2)-g(x)$$
it is the Leibniz rule, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 1):

Second Fundamental Theorem of Integral Calculus

> $$f'(x)=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left[\int_0^x g(t)\,\mathrm dt\right]$$

$$\begin{align}f'(x)&=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left[\int_x^{x^2}g(t)\,\mathrm dt\right]\\&=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left[\int_0^{x^2}g(t)\,\mathrm dt\right]-\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left[\int_0^x g(t)\,\mathrm dt\right]\\&=2x\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du}\left[\int_0^ug(t)\,\mathrm dt\right]-g(x)\\&=2xg(u)-g(x)\\&=2xg(x^2)-g(x)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to think about this is about areas under a curve instead of memorising rules.

So you imagine $g(t)$ as some graph of a function and you want the area under a bit of it. The boundaries of this bit depends on $x$ so how do they change when $x$ changes?

Well if $x$ increases by $\delta x$ then the boundary at $x^2$ moves onwards by $2x\delta x$ so the increase in area of $g$ corresponds to:
$$\int _{x^2}^{x^2+2x\delta x}g(t)\mathrm d t.$$
Which to a first order approximates as $2g(x^2)x\delta x.$ So the part of the derivative corresponding to increasing the boundary on the right is $2xg(x^2).$ Similarly on the left we get $-g(x).$ The minus sign comes because increasing the left boundary decreases the integral. Finally if $g$ depends on $x$ then the main body of the integral has $x-$derivative:
$$\int_x^{x^2}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\mathrm d t.$$

So in total:
$$\frac{\mathrm d f}{\mathrm d x} = -g(x) + \int_x^{x^2}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\mathrm d t + 2xg(x^2).$$